# How to get PK of last inserted item

Tags: mysql

I have an `INSERT` statement:

```
self.cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO mytable...''')
```

Is there a way to get the `pk` of the last entry? For example:

```
self.cursor.lastId
44
```

Comment: A suggestion is for you to sort by pk desc limit 1 and get the pk of that row

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will return it. MySQL Reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: @Royalty That is not guaranteed to be correct. If another record was inserted in between insert and getting pk using limit then it would return the wrong PK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LAST_INSERT_ID to get the id.

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

See this link for more details
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-last_insert_id.aspx